# Random selection of programs on my PC can't connect to the internet

Tags: windows-10, internet, internet-connection

Some of my programs won't connect to the internet, and I have no idea why. Some are blocked from connecting to the internet entirely, others aren't - it's a random selection. Not an ISP issue.

I'd usually know, but it's got to the point where I've even reset Windows 10 completely, and the problem has still propped back up after only a single reboot.

The thing is, it's only some of the programs on this machine that have problems. Others are completely fine.

For example, Firefox and Discord can connect to the internet completely fine. Battle.net client can't. Minecraft can connect to servers just fine, whilst I'm also not even able to login to NordVPN.

NordVPN has probably been the most helpful so far, as it's the only software that I'm able to get logs from. This is what I found popping up when trying to use the internet with it, edited to redact login domain:

```
INFO LoggingHandler Request POST https://[domain]/v1/users/oauth/login. Failed to get response: NordVpn.Core.Errors.BlockedEndpointException:  Failed to proceed request. Endpoint might be blocked.
```

Comment: Do you have NordVPN active when you try other systems? Either something like this blocks internet, or its on another device, such as the router that blocks it. You can isolate this by checking of other pc's or devices have similar issues.

Comment: It's not the internet that's the issue. I can confirm that other programs such as Battle.net and NordVPN all work on other devices. Tested this on my laptop just now, to double-check I'm not going mad.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: It looks like a trojan catching your network connection. it could be also due to broken DNS settings. From the command like try to ping servers that are not reachable (e.g. Battle.net server). If it can't detect the IP for the server based on the provided hostname - it's a DNS issue, check C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts

Comment: I doubt it's a trojan, as I've already reset my computer. After reinstalling all my programs, this problem's only popped back up. I doubt it's a DNS issue as well. I'm having to use an alternate VPN for the moment, but that's unfortunately not made any change to the issue.

Comment: I've come to find out that the error in System Settings was due to [a script I was running](https://github.com/undergroundwires/privacy.sexy/issues/110). That's now not an issue, but the issue still lies where I can't access internet on only some programs, whilst others work fine. Settings is telling me that I have no internet connection on the PC, even though I'm posting this comment on the very same device.

Comment: Tries: (1) Disable your security/antivirus software, (2) Disable the firewall.

Comment: Wish I could say that worked - if it did, I'd have not posted this. Unfortunately, neither of them have changed anything.

Comment: Do you use a proxy? Have you tried another DNS server ([example](https://developers.google.com/speed/public-dns))? Try also to reboot the router or even factory-reset it.

Comment: 1) Have you tried safe mode with networking ?  2) have you tried connecting with other means, for example tethering via USB from your smartphone ?

Comment: @harrymc - I usually use 1.1.1.1 anyway, but I've just tried default DNS settings as well, but to no avail. Tried Google DNS too.

Comment: @1NN - I've tried both safe mode w/ networking and tethering from my smartphone via USB, but to no avail.

Comment: The fact that only some programs and destinations are affected is very puzzling and seems to indicate a selective block. As you have reset Windows, this might be connected with the router - is the firmware fully updated?

Comment: @harrymc It's a router from Sky, so there's not really any firmware updates to perform on it - I've tested on a Win10 VM by installing almost all the same software with no issues, so it massively confuses me as to why this is happening on this specific machine

Comment: You mean that a VM on this host works perfectly well? This excludes the router and seems to point to some software that's installed on your computer. As this happens in Safe mode with Networking, this means the problem is in Windows. Try: (1) [Dism /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/7808-use-dism-repair-windows-10-image.html) and then [sfc /scannow](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/2895-run-sfc-command-windows-10-a.html).

Comment: @harrymc Gave that a go when I originally tried (I probably should've listed everything I've done so far, but I can't fully remember). I'm having a go again whilst typing, but I don't expect I'll get far. Will edit this in the next hour if there's a fix from it, though.

Comment: To add - just tried my other ethernet port (yes I have two), and I've not modified the settings on that adapter thus far. Yet, no resolution. I've also had a look at some articles where they all say to either reset network adapters or reset proxy settings. Unfortunately, neither of those got me anywhere.

Comment: For me, the VM test has shown that this is a problem with your setup, but I can't say what it is or what it could be.

Comment: One thing that's worth noting from testing - everything worked fine when I originally reset. It was somewhere along the line when re-installing everything that it all came crashing down again. Yet, the VM is fine when it's almost identical.

Comment: One thing I've just discovered this morning- when logging into Teams from the same setup, I discovered that I can't log into my personal Teams account ("No internet", 0x800706d9) but I can log into my work Teams account with no issue whatsoever. Had a Google and taken a look at some solutions, but none of them seem to help at all.

Comment: From your tests, it's even more probable that this problem is caused by some installed product. You may perhaps use [Autoruns](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/autoruns) to turn off startup items to find the problematic product.

Comment: I just had a go with Autoruns, restarting many times whilst disabling everything to the point where only Microsoft services were enabled. Unfortunately, nothing changed.

Comment: Last tries: (1) Boot in Safe Mode with Network and check. If this doesn't change anything: (2) Disable temporarily Windows Defender and Windows Firewall.

Comment: After a hiatus, I've finally managed to get round to trying the last resorts on my PC. I booted into Safe Mode with Networking, and everything worked fine. I restarted and booted normally, and weirdly enough - everything is fixed. I have absolutely no idea why or how, but everything is working perfectly fine again.

(Apart from Spotify, no idea what's up with that)